# Openshift not displaying application at given URL

Tags: openshift

I've been trying to deploy my own application up to openshift, and I followed the instructions and have started the Tomcat 7 instance, MySql cartridge and all seems to be running.

When I hit the site url, it shows the default openshift information page, my application is written using JSP/Servlet, mySQL.

On pushing the code to git, as far as I can tell the push went ok. See attached output.

I have an index.jsp in my application, and have set a welcome file mapping to urlPattern /home, as shown in the web.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>post/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

The push to openshift/git:

```
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 52.392s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 18 14:36:05 EDT 2014   
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/77M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 527129b9
remote: Activating deployment
remote: + tmp=/var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//tmp
remote: + '[' -d /var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//tmp ']'
remote: + for d in '$tmp/*'
remote: + '[' -d '/var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//tmp/*' ']'
remote: + '[' -d /var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//work/ ']'
remote: + rm -rf /var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//work/
remote: ++ ls /var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/app-root/runtime/repo//webapps
remote: + '[' ROOT.war ']'
remote: + rsync -r --delete /var/lib/openshift/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/app-root/runtime/repo//webapps/ /var/lib/opensh
ft/53516eaa4382ec7e990002c3/jbossews//webapps/
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: Found 127.6.235.1:8080 listening port
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Sorry for the newbie approach, but its my 1st time :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the approach i would take to troubleshoot. Since you didn't mention the exact error message, I would refer to generic troubleshooting. This can be used for any "route not working" problem

The Communication flow is 
Browser > Route > service > pod

Stand up another pod which curl installed.

First curl to pod IP address (You can get pod if from pod description or `oc get pod -o wide` )

If it works as expected, move to next layer that is service

curl to the service ip or hostname (oc get svc , the Cluster-ip is of our interest here)

If this works, then you can try reaching out to the route url.

This way you can determine where exactly it is breaking